# Check if data exists in cloud kit

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

My App does some importing when its first setup. I have it set to store core data in cloud kit.

My issue is if you run it on one device, everything imports fine. Run it on a second, and it will import for a second time, duplicating the records.

I'm trying to see if there's a way of checking if there is anything in cloud kit before running the import, but I'm always getting back false, even if I know there are records.

The code I'm using to check is

```swift
NSLog("Existance Check")
        checkIfExistsInCloudKit() { (result) in
            print(result)
            if result == false {
                NSLog("Does Not Exist")
                //let ImportData : ImportData = ImportData(viewContext: viewContext)
                //ImportData.importAll()
            } else {
                NSLog("Does Exist")
            }
        }
        NSLog("Existance Check Complete")
```

and the function is

```swift
func checkIfExistsInCloudKit(_ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    var result = false
    
    let container = CKContainer(identifier: "******")
    let privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "CD_brand = %@", "DMC")
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "CD_Colour", predicate: predicate)
    privateDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { records, error in
       //guard let records = records else { return }
        result = true
    }
    
    completion(result)
}
```

The results of printing give

> 2023-04-15 14:07:28.092262+0100 Stitchers Companion[4553:113693] Existance Check

> false

> 2023-04-15 14:07:28.092897+0100 Stitchers Companion[4553:113693] Does Not Exist

> 2023-04-15 14:07:28.092962+0100 Stitchers Companion[4553:113693] Existance Check Complete

Comment: Move "completion(result) inside the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the cloudkit zone -

```
let zoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: "com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone")

privateDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: zoneID) { records, error in // etc
```

This works for me, with pretty much the exact same scenario.